# Is there a way to refer to a cell in excel, based on another cells position?

Tags: excel, reference

My problem is, that I want to make a spreadsheet and i need to write a function.
The function is pretty simple. The problem is, that i need to repeat that function around 50-100 times and the position of the cells that i calculate from always changes.

For example:
"BD9" is a group cell of "BD9" "BE9" "BF9" "BG9"
"BD10" is a group cell of "BD10" "BE10" "BF10"
"BG10" is a single cell

In "BD9" there is a function that uses "BD10" and "BG10".
I want to make it, so that the function uses the valuse, based on the cell where the function is.
So based on the position of "BD9", "BD10" is under "BD9" and "BG10" is on the right of "BD10".

I would like to do it this way, cause the positions of the cells relative to the cell that has the function never changes.

So this way I dont need to change the values of so many functions.

And my second question is:
Can a cell refer to itself?

Like you use the "this" keyword.

My job would be so much easier if there was a way, but sadly i've been searching around for 3 days and found nothing about it.

---

Edit:
Here is a layout that i need to use and this layout needs to be copied multiple times.

[image: Visual representation]

Comment: Using `=CELL("address",A1)` you can get the absolute reference of that cell - is that what you need?  `CELL` can also return column and row numbers, etc.  Cells can never refer to their own values, this causes circular formula errors I'm afraid!

Comment: 1. You may be able to change to `R1C1` notation instead of the usual `A1` notation. Read Microsoft Help to learn about that. 2. Yes it can. This is a circular reference and you will need to enable `iterative calculations` for it to be effective. Again, read Help to learn about this.

Comment: @bcg I dont see how CELL would help because then i need to write the CELL function too, and in the meantime, i could just wrote the whole stuff. What i meant is, that we have a cell and to use the neighbor cells for a function. I also try to post a visual example on a small scale so its more clear.

Comment: Yes please, I don't quite understand what you're trying to do, so some sort of further example / explanation would be helpful.

Comment: @bcg I updated the post, it only allowed me to post a picture like this, because im new.

Comment: What cell is your formula in?  And what cells will the other formulas be in?

Comment: Take a look at the OFFSET() function of EXCEL, it can create an arbitrary range a set distance from a base reference cell.

Comment: tbh from what you've posted I don't really understand why you can't simply copy/paste the formula - do you mean you want to have a formula in one cell that inserts the result in another cell?

Comment: @bcg 

I could have copy/pasted the formula, but that means I need to copy/paste it around 80-100 times, that means i need to edit the cells that are in the formula. Now if I use the offset function, then I dont need to edit the cell references, tbh I ended copy/pasteing anyway, but this way i dont need to spend time changing the formula  for every instance around 100 times. Without offset I need to rewrite the formula(or at least edit what needs to be edited).

The example formula is a shortened version(that was for showing why cell positions matter).
The original  is 5-6 times the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "positions of the cells relative to the cell " ,

"based on the position of "BD9", "BD10" is under "BD9" >> `=OFFSET(BD9,1,0)`

"and "BG10" is on the right of "BD10"." >> `=OFFSET(BD10,0,3)`

> "Can a cell refer to itself?"

Directly, no. but if you intent to use it as input for the above relative position formula, yes.

"based on the position of "BD9", "BD10" is under "BD9" >> in Cell BD9 put : `=OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address"),BD9),1,0)`

"and "BG10" is on the right of "BD10"." >> in Cell BG10 put : `=OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address"),BD10),0,3)`

Comment: Yes! That's what i was looking for.
Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I  had edited the 2nd answer reflecting that CELL should input the reference cell too.. If you are only using one `CELL("address")` this function work just fine.. but if to you need to use it multiple time in the same excel file.. `CELL("address",A1)` is better (no buggy run). ( :